# How to output/build different JS files without shared chunks?

Tags: vite

I'm working on project using Vite, and I've run into a bit of a challenge that I hope some of you might help with. My project called delta-starter, is a JavaScript/Webflow starter template to have enchanced DX when using JS with Webflow.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I want each entry point in my Vite project to have its own bundle, with no shared chunks between them. So, for example, if two scripts (main.js and about.js) both use GSAP, I want each script to have its own copy of GSAP in its code.
[This is happening now. What I want is to have only dist/main.js & dist.about.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUhvR.png)
I want this because this is the way we will inject the scripts inside the Webflow editor for each page. No HTML/CSS, I just need independed JavaScript files with full functionality

What I've done so far:
I've been tweaking the vite.config.js to control how chunks are split using Vite's and Rollup's build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks. The idea is to avoid shared chunks for common imports/dependencies. But it's been a bit tricky, and I'm looking for some insights or suggestions on how to do this effectively.
Here's how it looks right now:

```
 build: {
            rollupOptions: {
                // Direct string paths without path.resolve
                input: entryPoints,
                external: ['jquery'],
                output: {
                    format: 'es',
                    entryFileNames: (chunkInfo) => `${chunkInfo.name}.js`,
                    chunkFileNames: '[name]-[hash].js',
                    manualChunks(id) {
                        if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
                            // Prevent bundling node_modules into common chunks
                            return null;
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
        },
```

Feel free to check out the code, and I'm all ears for any suggestions, ideas, or guidance you can provide. Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Almost everything, playing with manualChunks with no luck.